# How to place returned JSON data in a HTML Form

Tags: java, json, ajax, jax-rs

I need to place returned `JSON` data in HTML Form. I called database using web services and get JSON data. What I want is to place these JSON data into HTML input fields.

Sample JSON data (Returned as an array)

```
[{"username":"demo","email":"demo@gmail.com","password":"123"}]
```

The code in List.jsp

```
<form>
    Enter Username:<br>
    <input type="text" id="usernameEn" name="username"><br>
    <button id="btnGet">Get</button>
</form>
    <br><br>
<form>
    Username:<br>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br>
    Email:<br>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br><br>
    Password:<br>
    <input type="text" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#btnGet").click(function(event) 
        {
            event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url:  "http://localhost:8080/WebServiceTest2/webresources/users/get/" + $('#usernameEn').val(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                var userDetails = data;
                renderDetails(userDetails);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error: ' + textStatus);
            }
        });
    });
});

function renderDetails(data)
{
    $('#username').val(data.username);
    $('#email').val(data.email);
    $('#password').val(data.password);
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your REST service is returning an array, so to populate the form you'd have to access the first element of the array:

```
$('#username').val(data[0].username);
$('#email').val(data[0].email);
$('#password').val(data[0].password);
```

Or you could do the assignment higher up so you don't have to change your `renderDetails()` function:

```
var userDetails = data[0];
```

Probably best to also add a check to see whether the returned array is not empty.

Comment: It worked. Thanks, Robby Cornelissen. And how can I add series of data like, [{"username":"demo","email":"demo@gmail.com","password":"123"},{"username":"demo2","email":"demo2@gmail.com","password":"123"},{"username":"demo3","email":"demo3@gmail.com","password":"123"}]